Issue with Lazy loading OneToMany Hibernate - Java
I'm studying Spring and Hibernate and for my test I have this these classes (tables) with oneToMany and ManyToOne relationships:
@Entity
@Table(name = "photo")
public class Photo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(length = 200, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String url;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
    
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    
}


@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    
    @OneToMany(
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<Photo> photosIterable;
    
    
    
    public Set<Photo> getPhotosIterable() {
        return photosIterable;
    }
    public void setPhotosIterable(Set<Photo> photosIterable) {
        this.photosIterable = photosIterable;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}

when I run this instruction final User userNew = userRepository.findById(1).get();, so long as I set fetchMode to Lazy I would have expected that "photosIterable" to be empty because I know that with lazy fetch mode, different to EAGER, I load only info about User table and If I want his photos too I have to call get method  getPhotosIterable() , this is right? what I wrong?
In attachment you can see what I see inside userNew object and I see a infinite loop inside photosIterable

I tried to set fetch mode to lazy and I would have expected that photos set inside user object it be empty but like you can see by screenshot it isn't
EDIT:
this is what I see by JSON response by Postman


"I tried to set fetch mode to lazy and I would have expected that photos set inside user object it be empty but like you can see by screenshot it isnt" - JPA injects proxies for the sets that fetch the data from the database "when needed". This means: in the moment we observe the set (e.g. when we open it in the debugger), the entities get fetched.

@turing85 I also thought of something like this but if I set a rest controller and display the response json I still see all the fields populated (and I see the infinite loop) - tested by Postman

@Turing85 I edit my question with postman screenshot response

Of course you will. The mapper (probably jackson) will iterate over all elements of the collection, thus triggering the lazy load. If the connection were closed at this point in time, we would see a LazyInitializationException.

Can you explain better please? I dont understand what I wrong, I would like get only user with photosIterable empty for a performance issue as I avoid doing joins which I didn't need at the moment and I thought the solution was set to fetch mode to lazy @turing85

It seems that it is a JSON serialization issue.  @JsonIgnore should solve the problem.

if I use JsonIgnore it works in the sense that I don't see that iterable in the response JSON but two things aren't clear to me: 1) even using the annotation I don't see them in the json but they are there in the model so the query to obtain that data has been done, therefore if I had 3/4 fields ManyToOne would still have to do a lot of joins and this is what I would like to avoid 2) assuming I wanted to valorise that field (photosIterable) based on a condition, how can I do it given that the annotation is a fixed thing? @Raymond Choi
